Seeking Insights on PyFlink vs Java API for Apache Flink
I'm currently exploring different options for stream processing and am particularly interested in Apache Flink. I've noticed that Flink supports both PyFlink (Python API) and the Java API, and I'm trying to decide which to use for my upcoming projects.
Could anyone who has used these APIs share their experiences? I'm particularly interested in:
Performance: How do PyFlink and Java API compare in terms of speed and resource management?
API Availability: Is there a significant difference in what both APIs provide?
Ecosystem Integration: How well does each API integrate with other data tools and systems? Are there any limitations?
Use Case Suitability: Are there specific use cases where one API clearly outshines the other?
Community and Support: Which API has better community support and resources for troubleshooting?
Any detailed comparisons, pros, cons, or even specific anecdotes from your projects would be greatly appreciated. Your insights will help me make a more informed decision.

For the past month, I have been attempting to use Pyflink in hopes of creating an ETL application with Flink. What an absolute nightmare it has been.
For starters, Pyflink is simply a wrapper for the Flink Java API, and wow is it limited. You are unable to extend classes through Pyflink, as the implementation is written in Java, and you would need to create a custom jar file in order to implement a custom extended function (such as a FileSource/FileSink).
The community support for Pyflink is pretty much non existent. I have seen several posts on stackoverflow from years ago with no responses.
So, if you are planning on creating an application where you can COMPLETELY use Java, go with the Java API, as I am sure it would be much easier to work with and the community support is abundant.
